# input validation on HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA

Tags: php, security

I'm using jQuery webcam plugin from xarg.org, this plugin allow to use user webcam thanks to flash application and take snap.

When taking a snap, image is sent to php script for saving image by HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA. The author propose this script:

```
<?php
$str = file_get_contents("php://input");
file_put_contents("/tmp/upload.jpg", pack("H*", $str));
?>
```

My problem is the input validation, I don't know how to test data from HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA.

I add this test after the previous script:

```
$imageOK=true;
$imagesize = getimagesize("views/img/order.jpg");
if(@is_array($imagesize)){
    if($imagesize[mime]!="" && $imagesize[mime]=="image/jpeg"){
        $imageOK=true;
    }
    else {
    $imageOK=false;
    }
} else {
    $imageOK=false;
}
if(!$imageOK)
    unlink("views/img/order.jpg");
```

Do you think it is secure? If not, which kind of test can I do?

Thanks

Comment: Side note — I don't think `is_array()` will ever trigger a warning you need to silence with `@`. However, `mime` is an undefined constant that will throw a notice. I suggest you check the error reporting settings in your PHP development box.

Answer (score 0):

You check the file type with `getimagesize()`, which is good and secure.

But I don't see on your code any validation of the file **size**.

The golden rule is to never trust input from the client. So you should check server-side the size of the file.

You can check the Owasp website, which gives some good practices about file upload : https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Unrestricted_File_Upload